# Why is Facebook api Privacy parameters- custom - allow ignoring friend id's?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am unable to allow specific user id's to see my uploaded photo via the privacy parameters. This is my code:

```
$privacy = array(
    'value' => 'CUSTOM',
    'allow' => '619211114855652',

    ); 



$photo = (new FacebookRequest(
$session,
'PHOTO',
'/me/photos',
array (
    'source' => new CURLFile ($location.$name),
    'message' => ($caption),
    'privacy' => json_encode ($privacy)

 )

))->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray();
```

The friend id is retrieved using the get /me/friend request but this is being ignored as when I run this, it sets to "only me" as my privacy setting. Having googled this, I found out that if CUSTOM and allow is not specified, it will by default set it to "only me" who can see the post. When I replace the id with "ALL_FRIENDS" it works. I really do not understand why it isn't working, I assume facebook is ignoring the id but I can't think why. Has anyone managed to set their privacy to specific users?
Also note, this does not override my max privacy settings of the app, as my max setting is set to "friends". And I am just trying to limit the friends who can see the post.

Comment: My initial privacy setting is already set to "friends"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug. I reported it and now it works :)

Comment: I am facing the issue. Could you share the bug link or the patch?

Comment: @PiyushArora I am struggling to find the link to the bug. But the above code works. I didn't change anything, it was a bug and when it got fixed, my code worked.

Comment: It was not bug in my version but I missed the Niraj Shah's reply. Thanks, anyways.

Answer (score 2):

I've tested your code with a new application and I've found that it's the initial privacy setting you sent when adding the application causes this behaviour.

Go to Settings > Apps > Your App and change the "Visibility of App" setting to `Friends` or `Public`.

[image]

Then re-test your code and you'll see that it does indeed work work with a valid friend ID.

Comment: The initial privacy setting is already set to "friends" :S could it be anything else that could cause it to not work?! Is it working for you??

Comment: Hello, sorry, can you please explain. Because without the friend id, it works and I am able to share among friends because my initial privacy setting was set to friends. Why is the friend id being ignored?

Comment: This is working for me. It could be the privacy setting of the friend you are trying to tag. Have you tried it with other Friend IDs.

Comment: Privacy settings for all my test users are all set to "friends". Am I right in using the friend id from get /me/friends? :S At least I know now it works.. urgh but so annoying. I really cannot figure out why it isn't working for me. If I have an invalid ID I get an error. However when it's the valid one... it just ignores it :S hmmmmmmm